# Logic App filter on SharePoint Connecter Created by Display Name

Tags: odata, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to filter a SharePoint list based on a custom column (Employee) that is a user based lookup by DisplayName value in Azure Logic Apps with SharePoint Get Items.  I would like to not use the For Each/Condition solution, because it's slow.  I've tried  the following.

Filter - Employee/DisplayName eq 'customer name' (error column does not exist)
Employee - Employee eq 'customer name' (everything comes back or nothing.  I've tried a few variations.)

I also tried adding expand in various fashions (below) in the code view with various values in either the expand or filter.

```
  "queries": {
          "expand": "Employee/DisplayName",
           "$filter": "Employee eq 'Customer Name'"                            
                    }
```

and

```
              "queries": {
                    "$expand": "Employee/DisplayName",
                     "$filter": "Employee eq 'Customer Name'"                            
                    }
```

I feel like I'm just missing something easy.  It seems this would be a filter people would use often.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`$expand` is not in the list of the available parameters for the "[Gets items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items) from a SharePoint list" action. Only the following parameters would be recognized: `$filter`, `$orderby`, `$top`, `folderPath`, `view`, `viewScopeOption`.

`"$filter": "Employee eq 'Customer Name'"` should work fine if `Employee` is returned as a string, not as a JSON object. You can check it in the "Get items" action outputs.

Please note that you also have the option of getting *all* items from the list and then filtering them using the [Filter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) action.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an additional step:
Get List views prior to Get items. Then go back to Get items in the Filter Query to type your query (eg., stringColumn eq 'String').